# Ruby Rails - Cloud9 - (SocketError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, sockets, tcp, ide

When trying to start my Rails app in C9.io, I see the Socket Error below. I am unsure how to correct this issue. Any ideas?

- ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
- Rails 4.2.5
- Cloud9 IDE

  ```
  blacknight659:~/jh_projects/mybay2 $ rails s -b -$IP -p -$PORT
  ```

  => Booting WEBrick
  => Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://-0.0.0.0:-8080
  => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
  => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
  [2016-07-26 17:43:06] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
  [2016-07-26 17:43:06] INFO  ruby 2.3.0 (2015-12-25) [x86_64-linux]
  Exiting
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:231:in `getaddrinfo': getaddrinfo: Servname not supported for ai_socktype (SocketError)
          from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:231:in`foreach'
          from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:757:in `tcp_server_sockets'
          from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/utils.rb:65:in`create_listeners'
          from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:134:in `listen'
          from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:115:in`initialize'
          from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:47:in `initialize'
          from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:31:in`new'
          from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:31:in `run'
          from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in`start'
          from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
          from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in`block in server'
          from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
          from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in`server'
          from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
          from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`'
          from /home/ubuntu/jh_projects/mybay2/bin/rails:9:in `require'
          from /home/ubuntu/jh_projects/mybay2/bin/rails:9:in`'
          from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
          from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in`call'
          from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
          from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in`run'
          from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
          from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in`load'
          from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
          from /home/ubuntu/jh_projects/mybay2/bin/spring:13:in`require'
          from /home/ubuntu/jh_projects/mybay2/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
          from bin/rails:3:in`load'
          from bin/rails:3:in `'

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when tried to start my Sinatra app on cloud9. It turned out that I was running the command : `$ bundle exec rackup -p $PORT -o $IP` with root user (su). Try to run it on normal user.

Answer (score 0):

You have a dash before ip and port arguments. The values of the arguments are specified without dashes. Try:

```
rails s -b $IP -p $PORT
```